# Static PHP Calendar using div tables

Tags: php, html, css

I need some help with generating a web calendar using PHP and Div tables. I was successful at creating the calendar using HTML table tags, but that is not XHTML compliant. I need to convert the calendar table to div tables. My code is below, I have spent some time to fix this, but had no luck. Can someone look the code below and tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php
                $date = time();
                $day = date('d', $date);
                $month = date('m', $date);
                $year = date('Y', $date);
                $blank = 0;

                $day_one = mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year);

                $title = date('F', $day_one);

                $week_day = date('D', $day_one);

                switch ($week_day) {
                    case 'SUN': $blank = 0; break;
                    case 'MON': $blank = 1; break;
                    case 'TUE': $blank = 2; break;
                    case 'WED': $blank = 3; break;
                    case 'THU': $blank = 4; break;
                    case 'FRI': $blank = 5; break;
                    case 'SAT': $blank = 6; break;
                }

                $days_in_current_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);

                echo "<div class='cTable'>
                        <div class='cTableRow'>
                            <div class='cTableHead'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>$title $year</span></div></div>";
                echo "<div class='cTableBody'>
                      <div class='cTableRow'>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Monday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Tuesday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Wednesday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Thursday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Friday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableCell'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Saturday</span></div>
                            <div class='cTableHead'><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Sunday</span></div>
                        </div></div>";
                $day_count = 1;

                echo "<div class='cTableBody'><div class='cTableRow'>";

                while ($blank > 0) {
                    echo "<div class='cTableCell'></div>";
                    $blank = $blank-1;
                    $day_count++;
                }

                $day_num = 1;

                while ($day_num <= $days_in_current_month) {
                    echo "<div class='cTableCell'>$day_num</div></div></div>";
                    $day_num++;
                    $day_count++;

                if ($day_count > 7) {
                    echo "<div class='cTableBody'><div class='cTableRow'>";
                    $day_count = 1;
                }
                }

                while ($day_count > 1 && $day_count <=7) {
                    echo "<div class='cTableCell'></div>";
                    $day_count++;
                }

                echo "</div></div></div>";

                ?>
```

[image: Nice Calender]
[image: Not So Nice Calendar]

Comment: I think your real question is: "Why isn't my HTML output XHTML compliant?" Which would probably make more sense if you had displayed HTML output as the PHP code is irrelevant. There is a w3c validator http://validator.w3.org/ that will take output and tell you exactly what is wrong with it. (Why are you trying to be XHTML compliant anyway?)

Comment: With all due respect that is not my question at all. I generated a nice calendar using HTML table tags and the PHP script you see above. I am having trouble creating the same calendar using div tables as HTML tables are not XHTML compliant. Make sense?

Comment: So you've got HTML output. You want to make that same HTML output XHTML compliant?

Comment: Yes. I replaced HTML tables with Div tables, but it messed up my nicely generated calendar. Now rows of the calendar appear in different locations of the web page. See the two images I posted in my question

Comment: Okay, now I understand. You are converting from a table to divs. This really has nothing to do with XHTML. Step one would be to update your post with the static HTML table and the static HTML divs output.

Comment: Well, my professor taught me that way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is here. You need to close the `divs` only when you change row

```
while ($day_num <= $days_in_current_month) {
    echo "<div class='cTableCell'>$day_num</div>";
    $day_num++;
    $day_count++;

    if ($day_count > 7) {
        echo "</div></div><div class='cTableBody'><div class='cTableRow'>";
        $day_count = 1;
     }
}
```

also in order to get the correct numeric representation of the first weekday you need to change this

```
$week_day = date('w', $day_one);
```

as you need to get "w" instead of "D"

Comment: Thank you, kind sir! The answer above solved my problem. The only thing I now need to figure out is why March 1st is on Sunday as oppose to Wednesday.

Comment: you need "w" instead of "D": `$week_day = date('w', $day_one);`